# While attempting to run "bundle exec rackup -p 9292", I get a invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, utf-8, runtime-error, ruhoh

I am attempting to set up a Ruhoh blog (like Jekyll), not super well versed in command line, but the docs claim it's very beginner friendly.

I have gotten to the `bundle exec rackup -p 9292` which will run a Ruby server for the static pages to be served on. But, I keep getting an error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bundler/gems/ruhoh.rb-1c7df99c4149/lib/ruhoh/parse.rb:29:in `rescue in page_file':
Error trying to read meta-data from /Users/Austen/blog-v2/themes/twitter/media/glyphicons-halflings-white.png. Check your folder configuration.
Error details: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (RuntimeError)
```

Why does this happen when following the standard procedure?

Comment: Have a look at this issue for pointers? https://github.com/ruhoh/ruhoh.rb/issues/277. Post back if you are still stuck on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in Ruhoh (fixed in commit https://github.com/ruhoh/ruhoh.rb/commit/1c7df99).

To work around it simply rename the `config.ru` file to something not using the `config` name such as `rackup.ru` and launch your preview server with:

```
bundle exec rackup -p 9292 rackup.ru
```

Alternatively you can specify this specific version in your `Gemfile` since it has no other modifications since Ruhoh 2.6:

```
gem 'ruhoh', :git => "https://github.com/ruhoh/ruhoh.rb.git", :ref => "1c7df99c4149d450259cafec444b41cccbe0fece"
```